# Table width, vsapce, will not align correctly on wordpress template

Tags: wordpress

My table will not align correctly on this link:

http://www.teampaulmitchellkarate.com/meet-the-team/

Is there something im missing with the CSS/hspace vsapce?

I know a bunch of links are the same but its the layout I'm concerned about.

Comment: which element exactly are you referring to in the linked page?

Comment: The main table #1 keeps on erasing half my data in it and #2 doesn't display what i coded. so im not sure how to answer your question

Comment: i tried to post the code here but wouldn't let me

Comment: 3Cdesign: you can try pasting it at http://jsbin.com and link to it.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ijisov/4/edit#html,live

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just incorrect HTML syntax. You have several places with extra quotation marks before the word align (`"align=`)

A corrected version is http://jsbin.com/owehit/edit#html,live

Comment: so i put in the updatd table code you gave me and its still aligned weird...    http://www.teampaulmitchellkarate.com/meet-the-team/

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, you're not explaining it very clearly. You should remove the <center> element because it's deprecated. You can set 'text-align: center' on the wrapper class, it centers the things. Other than that, you'll need to explain exactly what you want.